# J2EE test deployment conflict resolution how to?

Tags: deployment, jakarta-ee, testing, web-deployment

Just stuck with this problem

Developer A changed file aaa.jsp in his svn branch and then our admin deploy that version to the test server. Test starts.

Lets say 3 days later, developer B changed the file aaa.jsp in her branch and then our admin deploy that version to the test server. Test starts.

Right now Developer A's version has been overwriiten.

I am looking for a tool which stores test status(fail,pass,ongoing,ready for prod.) of deployed artifacts and find conflicted change set if any of the non tested file will be changed by other future deployments.

I mean there should be a notification If I want to deploy developer B's aaa.jsp to the test server, since Developer A's aaa.jsp is stll in testing phase

Best Regards

edit: no hudson or nothing :)

lets say the change on the jsp is just a css change

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a continuous integration application like [Hudson](http://hudson-ci.org/) or [Cruise Control](http://cruisecontrol.sourceforge.net/)?